# C++ convert an unsigned int in range [0, 2^n) to signed int in range [-2^(n-1), 2^(n-1) )

Tags: c++, bit-fields

At the outset, I realize what I did was bad. I relied on what is now (at least) undefined behavior, if not explicitly forbidden. It used to work, and I thought I was being clever. Now it doesn't and I'm trying to fix it.

I have positive power-of-2 numbers (FFT bin index, but not important). I want to effectively FFT-shift a set of bin indices by wrapping the second half of the values to the negative range. That is, given an FFT size of 512,

```
0 ... 255 -> 0 ... 255
256 ... 511 -> -256 ... -1
```

What used to work was

```cpp
template <size_t N>
struct Wrapper {
    int val : N;
};

auto constexpr index = 42u;
auto wrapper = Wrapper<9>{ index }; // warning: invalid narrowing conversion from "unsigned int" to "int"
auto val = wrapper.val; // signed value
```

This relied on the truncation of overflowed assignment, but was empirically tested and Just Worked(tm).

Now, it doesn't compile (cleanly).

How should I perform this conversion now?

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding, but isn't this just a standard sign extension from a selectable bit position? So for a 512 = 2⁹ point FFT, and `uint32_t x;`, you could call a function `map_uint_to_int (x, 9)` defined as follows: `int32_t map_uint_to_int (uint32_t a, int n) { uint32_t msb = 1u << (n - 1); return (int32_t)((a ^ msb) - msb); }`.

Comment: I don't think you are misunderstanding, but it's hard to read code in a comment. Please post an answer

Comment: In this case this question seems to be a duplicate of [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42534749/signed-extension-from-24-bit-to-32-bit-in-c)

Comment: apparently so, but I never would have found that question

Comment: I think the many `auto`-typed variables are very dangerous, it is not explicit, whether they are signed/unsigned or which length they have. But perhaps it is just me.

Comment: @Sebastian `auto` is like religion; either you "get it" or you don't. I won't discuss the benefits of `auto` here, but the typing is explicit, just on the right side of the assignment. What is missing are any implicit conversions because the declaration doesn't match the assignment.

Comment: Like 4 religions: *Always Auto*, *Almost Always Auto*, *Almost Always Avoid Auto*, *Always Avoid Auto*. Now updated with the people preferring concepts over auto and over specific types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
auto wrapper = Wrapper<9>{ index & (1 << (9 - 1)) ? long(index) - 2 * (1 << (9 - 1)) : index };
```

If, for some reason (e.g. performance), ternary is not preferred, then you might also try:

```
auto wrapper = Wrapper<9>{ long(index) - 2 * (index & (1 << (9 - 1))) };
```

Comment: I edited the question to make it clear that the initialization of `wrapper` is the problem. That said, I suppose a ternary operation is reasonable

Comment: @jwm Also, if - for some reason - you don't like ternary (e.g. it compiles to conditional jump and it's slow), you might translate it to multipltication: `index - (index & (1 << 9))`

Comment: I don't think this is working as desired, since 9-bit integers above 256 will have `1 << 8` set, not `1 << 9`. But it's not so hard to tweak, e.g. `index - 2 * (index & (1 << 8)). You could also use `index - ((index & (1 << 8)) << 1)`, but the expression is confusing enough as-is, and any modern compiler will compile the two to the same machine code when you tell it to optimize.

Comment: @Wintermute Yep, I had that error & fix while writing but apparently didn't update. Thanks for spotting!

Comment: I think there are also some cast issues to take care of, since if `index` is unsigned, all the intermediate results are also unsigned and cannot be negative. Come to think of it, if we can rely on C++20 or common practice before that, `int32_t(index) << 23 >> 23` could be the easiest and fastest way, making use of sign extension in bit shifts. Since C++20, signed ints are guaranteed to be two's complement, that's why that's required; before then it's implementation-defined (and all implementations defined it the same way).

Comment: @Wintermute Fixed to `long` which is signed. I wouldn't force 2's complement here (yet) as c++20 tag was not in the question, but it makes sense that you mentioned it in comments.

Answer (score 0):

As [njuffa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/780717/njuffa) suggested, the answer is (unintuitively, to me at least) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42536138). In practice, they are the same thing, but I was explicitly converting from an unsigned range to a signed range.

[lorro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6292621/lorro) gave a good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74483704), but I was left thinking there was a simplification missing.

I ended up creating a functor that passed my unit tests:

```cpp
template <unsigned N>
struct Wrapper {
    int operator()(unsigned bin)
    {
        auto constexpr sign_mask = (1u << (N-1));

        auto val = int(bin ^ sign_mask) - sign_mask;
        return val;
    }
};

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_tf_fft_shift_index)
{
    auto f = Wrapper<9>();
    auto n255 = f(255u);
    auto n256 = f(256u);
    auto n511 = f(511u);

    BOOST_TEST(n255 == 255);
    BOOST_TEST(n256 == -256);
    BOOST_TEST(n511 == -1);
}
```

This is the bit-twiddling magic I was hoping for.