# Counting Minimum Number of Bytes Required to Represent a Signed Integer

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

My task seems simple, I need to calculate the minimum number of bytes required to represent a variable integer (for example if the integer is 5, then I would like to return 1; if the integer is 300, I would like to return 2). Not referring to the data type int which is, as pointed out in comments, always just sizeof(int), I'm referring to a mathematical integer.  And I *almost* have a solution. Here is my code:

```
int i;
cin >> i;
int length = 0;
while (i != 0) {
    i >>= 8;
    length++;
}
```

The problem is that this doesn’t work for any negative numbers (I have not been able to determine why) or some positive numbers where the most significant bit is a 0 (because the sign bit is the bit that makes it one bit larger)... Is there any hints or advice I can get in how to account for those cases?

Comment: I believe in c++ shifting is undefined on `int` if its negative: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415895/is-left-and-right-shifting-negative-integers-defined-behavior

Comment: inspecting the int via a char array might be the better option

Comment: @vu1p3n0x: I believe right shifting a negative is always defined. Left shift is another story.

Comment: Start with the definition. How do you define "number of bytes required to store an integer"? Once you have a proper definition, the implementation should naturally follow. Anyway, my guess is, division would work better for this problem than bit shifting, since you are working with numbers and not bit patterns.

Comment: The answer is  "int length = sizeof(int);" but I doubt that's what you mean. Define the problem.

Comment: Why do you need this? Some goofy instructor assigned it?

Comment: Count how many bits the absolute value of the number requires. If it was negative, you need 1 more bit. From there you can figure out bytes.

Comment: The problem as posed makes no sense. You can count the number of bits required to represent a number from a given range.

Answer (score 1):

Stored as a single byte, 
Positive numbers are in the range `0x00` to `0x7F`
Negative numbers are in the range `0x80` to `0xFF`

As 2-bytes, 
Positive numbers are in the range `0x0000` to `0x7FFF`
Negative numbers are in the range `0x8000` to `0xFFFF`

As 4-bytes, 
Positive numbers are in the range `0x00000000` to `0x7FFFFFFF`
Negative numbers are in the range `0x80000000` to `0xFFFFFFFF`

You can use a function like the following to get the minimum size:

```
int getmin(int64_t i)
{
    if(i == (int8_t)(i & 0xFF))
        return 1;
    if(i == (int16_t)(i & 0xFFFF))
        return 2;
    if(i == (int32_t)(i & 0xFFFFFFFF))
        return 4;
    return 8;
}
```

Then for example, when you see `0x80`, translate it to `-128`. While `7F` is translated to `127`, and `0x801` should be translated to a positive number.

Note that this will be very difficult and rather pointless, it should be avoided. This doesn't accommodate storage of numbers in triple bytes, for that, you have to make up your own format.

Answer (score 0):

The range of signed numbers possible to store in x bytes ***in 2's complement*** is -2^(8*x-1) to 2^(8*x-1)-1. For example, 1 byte can store signed integers from -128 to 127. Your example would incorrectly calculate that only 1 byte is needed to represent 128 (if we are talking about signed numbers), as right shifting by 8 would equal zero, but that last byte is required to know that this is not a negative number.

For handling negatives, turning it into a positive number and subtracting one (because negative numbers can store an extra value) will allow you to right shift.

```
int i;
cin >> i;
unsigned bytes = 1;
unsigned max = 128;

if (i < 0) {
    i = ~i; //-1*i - 1
}

while(max <= i) {    
    i >>= 8;
    bytes++;
}
cout << bytes;
```

Another option is to use `__builtin_clz()` if you are using gcc. This returns the leading zeros, which you can then use to determine the minimum number of bytes.

Comment: You should right-shift `i` instead of left-shifting `max`, to avoid problems with reaching the upper limit of `max`.

Comment: Also, isn't that just `i = ~i;` ?