# What does <<= or >>= mean in Java?

Tags: java, assignment-operator

I was learning about assignment operators in Java in W3schools. But I didn't get what these two operators mean?

Comment: Those are short notation of left and right shift. Kinda like `+=`. It is explained on their website though. These are bit wise operations. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55203804/understanding-the-right-shift-operator-with-bit-shifting

Comment: These are [Compound assignment operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2), related to [Shift operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19)

Comment: [Compound assignment operators in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/compound-assignment-operators-java/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are examples of *assignment operators*. Essentially, they both perform the arithmetic operation on a variable, and assign its result to that variable, in a single operation. They're equivalent to doing it in two steps, for the most part:

```
int a = 23;
int b = 2;

a += b; // addition - same as `a = a + b`
a -= b; // subtraction
a *= b; // multiplication
a /= b; // floor division
a %= b; // modulo division
a &= b; // bitwise and
a |= b; // bitwise or
a ^= b; // bitwise xor
a >>= b; // right bitshift
a <<= b; // left bitshift
```

The bitshift operations in particular are the ones you're asking about. They take the binary representation of a number, and shift it left or right by the given number of places, filling in missing spaces with zeroes. For example, the binary representation of 23 is `00010111`.

So, `23 << 2` would be equal to `01011100`, or 92; whereas `23 >> 2` would be equal to `00000101`, or 5.

You could also think of it as doing integer multiplication or division using powers of two:

- `a << b` will generally produce the same result as `a * Math.pow(2, b)`
- `a >> b` will generally produce the same result as `a / Math.pow(2, b)`

Answer (score 1):

it's short expression, just like `i = i >> 2` and `i = i << 2`

Comment: I doubt they understand what that means. It would be better if you expand your answer so it is better. Like what does shifting left or right does.

Comment: my bad, I'm a new comer,I would rewrite my answer

Comment: Sure, you can [edit] your answer as many times as you want. People tend to vote on good detailed answer.

Comment: And it's not entirely true - with a compound assignment operator, the left hand side is only evaluated once.  This can be an important distinction.  Also, the type conversion rules are a bit different.