# Python function to return largest possible number of 64 bits

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, bit

Is there a python 3 funtion that will return the largest number of `N` bits?

Example:

```py
>>> print(largest_bitsize(8))
255
>>> print(largest_bitsize(16))
65535
```

Comment: No, there isn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Kevin's answer costs *O(log n)* in time complexity due to the use of the power operator.

A more efficient way to calculate the largest number of `n` bits would be to use bitwise shift and negation instead, which costs *O(1)*:

```
def largest_bitsize(n):
    return ~(-1 << n)
```

Comment: This answer is faster than @Kevins answer. Thank you!

Comment: Does Python allow you to shift a negative number like that? Does the language allow it, or does it just happen to work in this instance? (It seems to depend on representations, and that seems non-portable).

Comment: @jww It's how the binary system for negative numbers works. It's portable everywhere. See demo in [C](https://onlinegdb.com/BkVIprb1B) and [Java](https://repl.it/repls/TrustworthyMuddyLinuxkernel).

Comment: Thanks @blhsing - I believe that's [undefined behavior in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8415895/608639). In C you *can* shift an `int`, but it must be non-negative value. And of course you can shift an `unsigned`. I don't know about Java.

Comment: @jww The Python language deliberately makes this possible. The behaviour doesn't come out of the internal representation - in fact, the internal representation in CPython is sign-magnitude, so CPython has to go to extra effort to do the "right thing" and behave as though some form of infinite two's complement were being used.

Comment: @jww: Relevant documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bitwise-operations-on-integer-types. "The result of bitwise operations is calculated as though carried out in two’s complement with an infinite number of sign bits." (BTW, I usually spell this as `~(~0 << n)`, just for the symmetry...)

Answer (score 8):

I don't think there's a builtin one, but it's easy enough to write your own. 2^N is always the smallest number that requires N+1 bits, so (2^N)-1 must be the largest number that requires N bits.

```
def largest_bitsize(n):
    return 2**n - 1

print(largest_bitsize(8))
#result: 255

print(largest_bitsize(16))
#result: 65535

print(largest_bitsize(64))
#result: 18446744073709551615
```

Answer (score 6):

I also don't think there's a built-in func but you could write it out. Use a bit shift (as opposed to exponents) for even faster performance:

```
def largest_bitsize(b):
     return (1 << b) - 1
```

Answer (score 5):

How about this?

```
def largest_bitsize(n):
    return int('1' * n, 2)
```

Examples:

```
>>> int('1'*16, 2)
65535
>>> int('1'*64, 2)
18446744073709551615
```

Comment: Wasn't aware int() had a base parameter.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a less efficient way to do this:

```
def largest_bitsize( n ):
   return sum( [ 2 ** i for i in range( n ) ] )
```

Comment: It's less efficient but it illustrates some features of python nicely.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is not any BuiltIn is available. But you can try this..

```
def largest_bitsize(b):
    return (2**b) - 1
```

Output:-

```
>>> largest_bitsize(64)

18446744073709551615
```