# How does shift operator work with negative numbers in c++

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, bit-shift

```
int main() 
{
  int x = -2;

  cout << (1<<x) << endl;

  cout << (1<<-2) << endl;

}
```

Here the `(1<<x)` prints 1073741824 (how is this calculated)

Whereas `(1<<-2)` prints a garbage value.

And why do these two return different answers?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415895/is-left-and-right-shifting-negative-integers-defined-behavior

Comment: If the right number in a shift operation is negative, the result is undefined.

Comment: But then when I store -2 in a variable how does it not return garbage and always returns definite answer ?

Comment: Oh okay so the value - 1074741824 isint a reliable value and the result is undefined ?

Comment: @lurker - not a duplicate - that question refers to the lhs being negative, whereas this is the rhs.

Comment: @RichardMatheson sorry you're right. Read it to hastily.

Comment: Undefined behaviour means *anything* can happen, including contradictory things

Comment: "Oh okay so the value - 1074741824 isn't a reliable value and the result is undefined?"  Correct.  On my machine the result is that the program crashes.

Comment: "undefined behavior" means **only** that the language definition (the C++ Standard) does not tell you what the program does.

Answer (score 12):

According to the C Standard (6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators)

> 3 The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The
>   type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. **If the
>   value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to
>   the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined**

The same is written in the C++ Standard (C++20, 7.6.7 Shift operators)

> 1. ... The operands shall be of integral or unscoped enumeration type and
>      integral promotions are performed. The type of the result is that
>      of the promoted left operand. **The behavior is undefined if the right
>      operand is negative, or greater than or equal to the width of the
>      promoted left operand.**

Answer (score 2):

In the standard, http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf

Page 118, Section 5.8.1:

> The behavior is undefined if the right operand is negative, or
>   greater than or equal to the length in bits of the promoted left
>   operand

Meaning the compiler can do whatever it wants here - all bets are off.